# Java: display values based on sorted keys in hashmap

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I have a HashMap, i have sorted the categories and put it in a list ie initially the categories were : -  A,B,C,D and after sorting it is D,C,B,A and i've added it to the List.

I want to display questions based on the sorted order of category i.e
Display all questions with category :- D
then Display all questions with category :- C and so on.

here is what I've tried:-

```
   List<Category> list = Arrays.asList(Category.values());
     List<Question> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
     list1.addAll(questionList);


    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Category>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Category o1, Category o2) {
            return o2.ordinal() - o1.ordinal();

        }
    });
    System.out.println("Categories" +list);
    Map< List<Category>,List<Question>> map = new HashMap<>();

     map.put(list, list1);}}

   boolean ty = list1.containsAll(list1);
    if(ty==true){
  out.println(list1.get(0).getQuestion())  ;}
```

**i want my output to be like this:-**

D: what is your name?
   how are you?

C: another question1?
   another question2?

B: another question3?
   another question4?

Comment: It looks like you need a `LinkedHashMap<Category, List<Question>>` instead of `HashMap< List<Category>, List<Question>>`. That is because unlike `LinkedHashMap`, `HashMap` is not ordered, also, you need to use a single category as a key not an entire list of categories as a single key but, if you want to access the questions in a specific order, I'm not sure that `Map` is a good way of modeling your data.

Comment: I don't understand your choice of key type for your map.  Why a list of categories rather than just a single category as your key?

Comment: The code you have posted has no relationship to your described goal. It’s true that you should post your question with code, but it should be an *attempt to solve your problem*. The posted code does the following: • create a list of the predefined `Category` constants as `list`, • create a copy of the `questionList` as `list1`, • sort `list` to exactly the order it already has, • create a `Map` of a strange type, • compare `list1` with itself, • print `list1.get(0).getQuestion()` if `true==true`. So the entire code could be shortened to `out.println(questionList.get(0).getQuestion());`…

Answer (score 1):

> I want to display questions based on the sorted order of category i.e
>   Display all questions with category :- D then Display all questions
>   with category :- C and so on.

To perform your need, questions must be related to a category.

You have two ways of doing :

- using a comparator (as @Surace done) to sort all questions in a final list.
- creating a map (list of questions as value and category as key)

Comparator is more concise and it is rather a good idea but in your case it has a drawback, it doesn't keep the category associated to each question while you want it in your rendering :

> i want my output to be like this:-
>
> D: what is your name? how are you?
>
> C: another question1? another question2?
>
> B: another question3? another question4?

You may retrieve the information with category information stored in the question but it forces you to do rather clumsy processing during iteration because the category is not a external information but a computed information that you have to search in another object.

By creating a map which associates questions by category, you just need to iterate to render the information and in more general way you may perform any additional processing for each iteration of category.

Here the code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  // create your questions
  List<Question> questionsInput = new ArrayList<>();
  questionsInput.add(new Question("question 1 For A?", Category.A));
  questionsInput.add(new Question("question 2 For A?", Category.A));

  questionsInput.add(new Question("question 1 For A?", Category.B));
  questionsInput.add(new Question("question 2 For A?", Category.B));

  Map<Category, List<Question>> map = associateQuestionByCat(questionsInput);

  // display info
  for (Entry<Category, List<Question>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
      System.out.print("cat " + entry.getKey() + ":");
      for (Question q : entry.getValue()) {
        System.out.print(q.getQuestion());
      }
      System.out.println("");
  }

}

public static Map<Category, List<Question>> associateQuestionByCat(List<Question> questions ) {

  Map<Category, List<Question>> questionsByCategory = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());

  for (Question q : questions) {
    final Category currentCat = q.getCat();
    List<Question> questionsForCurrentCat = questionsByCategory.get(currentCat);
    if (questionsForCurrentCat == null) {
        questionsForCurrentCat = new ArrayList<>();
        questionsByCategory.put(currentCat, questionsForCurrentCat);
    }
    questionsForCurrentCat.add(q);
  }

  return questionsByCategory;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a hint: `Category` obviously is an `enum`, so you don’t need to implement a `Comparator` at all. You can just use `new TreeMap<>();`, but using an `EnumMap` instead of `TreeMap` would make it even more efficient.

Comment: @Holger The user waits for displaying Categories in the reverse order of Enum ordinals while with EnumMap, entries are maintained in the order of Enum ordinals.

Comment: Oh. The OP wants the categories *in reverse order*. That’s really nicely hidden… still, if you want to sort in reverse order, just use [`reverseOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder--) instead of implementing your own comparator. Then, every reader will immediately recognize the intention.

Comment: That time, I agree with you as it makes code shorter and it stays readable. I update :) Ah I forgot, the  comparator comes from the original code but it is not an excuse ;)

Comment: Note that `new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());` requires Java 8. In Java 7, you have to insert either, an explicit type, i.e. `new TreeMap<>(Collections.<Category>reverseOrder());` or a temporary variable, i.e. `Comparator<Category> cmp=Collections.reverseOrder(); … new TreeMap<>(cmp);`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give your expected output.

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Category>() {

      @Override
      public int compare(Category o1, Category o2) {
//       o1.getCategoryName() is A or B or C or D
         return o1.getCategoryName().compareTo(o2.getCategoryName()); 
        }
});
```

Comment: Did you get ? If not please let me know i will update my answer according to your requirement.

Comment: o1.getQuestion().substring(0,1) gives first letter of the question . I think it is A,B,C,D in your case .